# How to insert greek letters with subscript in text mode with latex?

Tags: packages, subscripts, greek

I am trying to insert a greek letter with subscript in latex and I used `textgreek` package and it appears as `h_a`. I am making a poster using `beamer` but I wrote following sample code and it has the same problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\begin{document}
 $\texteta \textsubscript{a}$
 \end{document}
```

Would you please help me? If the package `textgreek` is not good for mixing with subscript, please recommend other package that I can use.

Thank you!

Comment: Omit the `$` symbols.

Comment: what's the problem with `\texteta \textsubscript{a}`? (except that `\texteta` isn't allowed in math mode end `\textsubscript` makes no sense in math mode…)

Comment: If you actually want an upright eta in math mode you may want to use the `upgreek` package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\texteta` etc. isn't meant for math mode, i.e. omit the `$...$` characters -- that's why the symbols are called `\text...`, i.e. to be used in text mode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\begin{document}

\huge
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
Text mode & & Math mode \tabularnewline
\texteta \textsubscript{a} &  & $\eta_{a}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought that math mode can be only used in equations.